# how to make a list of numbers in a given string, javascript?

Tags: javascript, apex

Here is a string:  (1 AND 2) OR 30 AND (4 AND 5).
I need a list of numbers included in this string.
Please help me out.

Comment: string.match(/\d+/g)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **match**:

```
var numbers = "(1 AND 2) OR 30 AND (4 AND 5)"
var formatted = numbers.match(/\d+/g)
console.log(formatted); // [1,2,30,4,5]
```

Comment: Hey @jonathandion, I need 30, not 3 and 0 separately.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: If the answer is good you should accept it to close the question. Thanks.